# Get Request in Flutter:- 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'

Tags: api, flutter, http, get-request

I have added the http version to ^0.13.0 in pubspec.yaml file and I just need to get the Yes NO API request from the Public-apis.io to generate some Yes/No GIFs, while using the Get request it says,

The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri'.

Any solution for this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mawAQ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works:

```
Response response = await get(Uri.https("owlbot.info", "/api/v4/dictionary/"));
```

Or, with token and parameter:

```
 Response response = await get(Uri.https("owlbot.info", "/api/v4/dictionary/"+ _controller.text.trim()), headers: {"Authorization": "Token " + _token});
```

More info:
https://pub.dev/packages/http/example

Comment: Thanks for solving the issue but I'm wondering why do we need to put space between "owlbot.info" and "/api/v4/dictionary/"? I'm kind of new to Flutter can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 4):

You should use:

```
http.get(Uri.parse("https://yesno.wtf/api"))
```