# The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uri

Tags: flutter

[Hi, See the code I don't know from where the error message is comming i used url and in the error it's showing string can't be assign to the type uri. I did change the url type to string but still giving this error I'm following udemy course and i have copied the same file but still giving this error. Can anyone help me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0meB.jpg)

Comment: See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66508069/get-request-in-flutter-string-cant-be-assigned-to-the-parameter-type-uri/66508502#66508502)

Answer (score 2):

use following as your `url`

```
final url = Uri.parse("www.yourURL.here");
```

Comment: Thank you so much brother , Stay blessed